# Linq syntax error in ASP MVC controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I have a Linq query I need to use in my Index method in the page's controller, however I am getting the following error on the "select new" portion of the code:

**Error**

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'string'
```

**Action method**

```
    public ActionResult Index(string query)
    {

        var agentProductTraining = "";

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
        {
            BlankIndex();
        }
        else
        {
            agentProductTraining = from course in db.Course
                                   where
                                       course.CourseDescription.Contains(query)
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       course.CourseCode,
                                       course.CourseDescription,
                                       course.Partner,
                                       course.Status,
                                       course.LastChangeDate,
                                       course.LastChangeOperator
                                   };
        }

        return View(agentProductTraining.ToList());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've initialized the variable as a string, so the compiler makes the variable a `string` type (since you've user the `var` keyword), but then tried to assign a collection of anonymous types to it.

You can declare it as an `object` instead or `var`:

```
object agentProductTraining;  // can safely be overwritten
```

Also I assume you mean:

```
return BlankIndex();
```

in the `if` block.  Otherwise it will fall through to

```
return View(agentProductTraining.ToList());
```

where `agentProductTraining` is going to be `null`

Of course if you use `return BlankIndex` in the `if` block you can simplify the whole thing:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
{
    return BlankIndex();
}

// don't need an `else` here since the if will return to the caller
var agentProductTraining = from course in db.Course
                           where
                               course.CourseDescription.Contains(query)
                           select new
                           {
                               course.CourseCode,
                               course.CourseDescription,
                               course.Partner,
                               course.Status,
                               course.LastChangeDate,
                               course.LastChangeOperator
                           };

return View(agentProductTraining.ToList());
```

Comment: It would be better to do this:

    var agentProductTraining = new List<object>();

Then your return is a list still and is at the very least newed up.

Comment: It doesn't matter - the initialized value will get blown away by the assignment via `ToList()`.  It won't add the items to the initialized list.

Comment: Also you're not returning the _list_, you're returning a `View` that is initialized with an `object` in the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492930.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

As the error clearly states, you cannot assign the result of a LINQ query (`IQueryable<T>`) to a variable of type `string`.

You should declare the variable in that line:

```
var agentProductTraining = select ...
```

Comment: Except it will be scoped in the `else` block and not available to the `return` statement.